# For what values of $\alpha$ is this set compact?

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, compactness

I was given the set $M=\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | |x_1|^\alpha + |x_2|^\alpha \leq 1 \}$.

For which values of $\alpha$ is this set:
a) closed
b) compact
c) convex.

What I know: if a set is closed and bounded, then it's compact. And a closed set has to contain all limit points. So whatever works for b) will have to work for a). But I can't really figure out how to apply that theory.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\alpha>0$?

Comment: No, no such criterion.

Comment: Hint: Suppose that $\alpha<0$. Verify that the set $|x|^\alpha + |y|^\alpha\le 1$ is unbounded and  nonconvex. Next, analyze the case $\alpha\in (0,1)$...

Comment: Try to draw the set in the cases $\alpha=-1,0,1/2,1,2,\infty$. What do you see ?

Comment: @Carot Well, in the case of -1, the set is still closed (I think?) but unbounded, in the case of 0 it's empty, 1/2, 1 and 2 are both closed and bounded and I don't know how to draw the infinity one....

Comment: @Carot But I can see how the <0 case is unbounded. >0 seems compact but I'm not sure about infinity.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow \infty}\frac{|x_1|^\alpha+|x_2|^\alpha}{\max(|x_1|,|x_2|)^\alpha}=1$.

Comment: When $\alpha>0$, $(|x_1|^\alpha+|x_2|^\alpha)^{1/\alpha}$ is denoted $||(x_1,x_2)||_\alpha$. Note that $M=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 / ||x||_\alpha\leqslant 1\}$. By convention we set $||x||_\infty=\lim ||x||_\alpha=\max(|x_1|,|x_2|)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha<0$, then $M$ is unbounded (in particular, it is not compact) and disconneted (in particular, it is not convex).

If $\alpha=0$, then $M=\emptyset$, which is both compact and convex.

If $\alpha>0$, then $M$ is closed ($M=f^{-1}\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ with $f(x_1,x_2)=\lvert x_1\rvert^\alpha+\lvert x_2\rvert^\alpha$, and $f$ is continuous) and bounded; therefore it is compact. But it is convex if and only if $\alpha\geqslant1$ (if $\alpha\in(0,1)$, then $(1,0),(0,1)\in M$, but no point of the line segment joining them belongs to $M$).

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $\alpha < 0$, then the set is not compact for it is not bounded.
To show this, note that $(x_0, x_0) \in M$ for every $x_0 \ge \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/\alpha}$. (Simply check.)
It is not convex either. Note that $M$ isn't empty (by above exercise). So, pick any point $(x_0, y_0) \in M$. We also have that $(-x_0, -y_0) \in M.$ Now, $(0, 0)$ lies on the line segment joining these two points (it's the midpoint) but $(0, 0) \notin M$. We will later show that $M$ is closed.

If $\alpha = 0$, then the set is empty and all the properties are (vacuously) true.

Let us now assume that $\alpha > 0.$
One can straightaway note that $|x| \le 1$ and $|y| \le 1$. Thus, $M$ is bounded. This means that it is compact iff it is closed. We will later see that this is indeed the case. Let us first deal with convexity.

Claim 1. If $0 < \alpha < 1$, then $M$ is **not** convex.
*Proof.* Consider the points $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$. It is clear that these points belong to $M$.
Now, check that $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ is the midpoint of these points. However, it does not belong to $M$.
To check this, note that $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\alpha + \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^\alpha = 2^{1-\alpha} > 2^0  =1.$

Claim 2. If $\alpha \ge 1$, then $M$ **is** convex.
*Proof.* Use inequalities carefully.

Now, we show that $M$ is always closed irrespective of $\alpha$.

Note that the function $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto |x_1|^\alpha + |x_2|^\alpha$ is continuous and the set $M$ is simply the inverse image of the closed set $[0, 1]$. As inverse image of closed sets are closed under continuous maps, we are done.

---

To sum it up:
$\alpha < 0 : $ only closed
$\alpha = 0 : $ all
$0 < \alpha < 1:$ only closed and compact
$1 \le \alpha:$ all

Comment: Great answer, thanks. May I ask though, how do we know the function is continuous for all values of $\alpha$?

Comment: $x^\alpha := e^{\alpha \ln x}$ for $x \ge 0$. Continuity follows from continuity of $x \mapsto e^x$ and $x \mapsto \ln x$.